# Blocking ads using HOSTS at ROUTER Level

Tags: adblock

Using TP Link Archer C9 and D-Link DIR868L here.

Have been looking through the manual/guide to find DNS settings to redirect all spammy websites to null, but can't find it anywhere.

Would like to specify my own blacklist rather than depend on services such as Adguard.

Will also prefer to stick to my fast DNS - 1.1.1.1.

Hopeful for a solution from any guru here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Blocking websites is done via their IP address or website.

See the instructions for:

- [TP-Link](https://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1387.html)
  Use Access Control > Host, then click Add New… and set to blocked.
- [D-Link](https://eu.dlink.com/uk/en/support/faq/routers/mydlink-routers/dir-868l/how-do-i-set-up-website-filtering-on-my-router)
  Using a website filter in Settings > *DENY computers access to ONLY these sites*.